# For Loop not looping, Confirm the Ending

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to confirm the end of a string argument is identical to the target argument.

How come my for loop is not looping? To me, the str.substr(-i) should keep increasing and eventually match the target argument.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
     if (str.substr(-i) === target) { 
        return true;
     }
     else {
        return false;
     }
  }
}

confirmEnding("Bastian", "n");
```

Comment: Because you are returning on the first iteration. The return keyword will exit the function.

Comment: Why are you looping to get the last character(s)? And shouldn't you using target in the loop, not str?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could check.

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
// get the last n letters of the string where n is the length of the target
// then compare that to the target
  return str.substr(str.length - target.length, target.length) === target;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "n")); // true
console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "ian")); // false
console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "i")); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the return keyword. Here is a functional Example of what you want:

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
    var result = false;
    for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
        if (str.substr(-i) === target) { 
            result = true;
        }   
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative**

Try `.endsWith()` **(ES6)**?

**Example:**

```
'Bastian'.endsWith('n'); // true
```

> **Ref:** [String.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) *(Check browser supports / Polyfill)*

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
      // "Never give up and good luck will find you."
      // -- Falcor
      var newStr;
      newStr=str.substr(-target.length,target.length);
      if(newStr===target){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
    }
    }

    confirmEnding("Bastian", "n");
```